# Generate infinite DoubleStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can generate `Stream<Double>` using `generate`. E.g.

```
Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

How to generate infinte random `DoubleStream` instead of `Stream<Double>`?

Comment: It’s a funny question as just replacing `Stream` with `DoubleStream` in your question’s code would do. But without asking you hadn’t learned about the stream factory methods of the `Random` class…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Random#doubles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles--) to generate`DoubleStream`

> Returns an effectively unlimited stream of pseudorandom double values,
>   each between zero (inclusive) and one (exclusive). A pseudorandom
>   double value is generated as if it's the result of calling the method
>   nextDouble().

E.g.

```
new Random().doubles().limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Also `new Random().doubles(10).forEach(System.out::println);`.

Comment: and also [other](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles-double-double-) [overloads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles-long-double-double-) allow setting of bounds

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try this:

```
   DoubleStream i = DoubleStream.generate(new Random()::nextDouble);
   Stream<Double> o =  i.boxed();
   o.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can read more about them here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)

Comment: Do you really need `.boxed()`?